# Application of Slutsky's Theorem to the Convergence of Sum of R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2,…, X_n$ be i.i.d. $U(−\theta,\theta)$. Show that $Z_n \to N(0,\sqrt{5/9})$ in distribution, where $Z_n =\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}^{3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}^{4}}{n}}}$

My solution so far:
This should just be a direct application of CLT, WLLN, and Slutsky's theorem.  The top term converges by the CLT to $N(0,\sigma^2)$, but I'm not sure what $\sigma^2$ is.  Is it just $Var[U(-\theta,\theta)]$?  In the denominator, $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}^{3}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}^{4}}{n}$ converges to $E[X_1^3]+E[X_1^4]$ by the WLLN.  The last step is to apply Slutsky's Theorem.  Since $X_i$ are $U(-\theta,\theta)$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{1}{2\theta}$.  Then $$E[X]=\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\frac{1}{2\theta}xdx=0\\E[X^2]=\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\frac{1}{2\theta}x^2dx=\frac{1}{3}{\theta}^3\\
E[X^3]=\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\frac{1}{2\theta}x^3dx=0\\E[X^4]=\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\frac{1}{2\theta}x^4dx=\frac{1}{5}{\theta}^5
$$

So $\operatorname{Var} [U(-\theta,\theta)]=\frac{1}{3}{\theta}^3$.  At this point I can't get the algebra to work out.  I don't know if incorrectly computed the moments.

Comment: Without going further: $\mathbb{E}[X^4] = \frac{\theta^4}{5}$. This is convenient, as taking the $\sqrt[4]{\cdot}$ you will be able to get rid of $\theta$ from the variance in the CLT (from the numerator). As for the variance of a uniform distribution on $(a,b)$, it is $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$.

Comment: It seems like you are basically done.  Clement points out an error in your $E[X^4]$ calculation (you are off by a factor of $\theta$).  You also have the same type of error in your $E[X^2]$ calculation.  The algebra indeed works out when you make the corrections.

Comment: I am a little confused still.  If $E[X^4]=\theta^4/5$ then $\sqrt[4]{\frac{\theta^4}{5}}=\sqrt[4]\frac{1}{5}\theta$.  The variance ends up being $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}=\frac{(-\theta-\theta)^2}{12}=\frac{4\theta^2}{12}=\frac{ \theta^2}{3}$.  Then when we apply Slutsky's theorem the resulting variance is $\frac{\frac{\theta^2}{3}}{\sqrt[4]\frac{1}{5}\theta}=\frac{\theta\sqrt[4]{5}}{3}$.